# Proper response for a REST insert - full new record, or just the record id value?

Tags: rest

I'm building a REST API which allows inserts (POST, not idempotent) and updates (PUT, idempotent) requests to add/update database to our application.

I'm wondering if there are any standards or best practices regarding what data we send back to the client in the response for a POST (insert) operation. We need to send back at least a record ID value (e.g. your new record is record #1234).

Should we respond with the full object? (e.g. essentially the same response they'd get back from a "GET /object_type/1234" request)

Should we respond with only the new ID value? (e.g. "{ id: 1234 }", which means that if they want to fetch the whole record they need to do an additional HTTP GET request to grab the full record)

A redirect header pointing them to the URL for the full object?

Something else entirely?

Comment: I'm oot sure about best practice but for me personally I would probably consider just returning the newly created id if successfull otherwise -1 etc  Be interested to see what others say though

Answer (score 15):

Well, in a REST interface, following HTTP where ever possible, I would return a 201 and an URI in the Location header field to the newly created Resource. Here is what [Status Code Definitions](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) says:

> **10.2.2 201 Created**
>
> The request has been fulfilled and resulted in a new resource being
>   created. The newly created resource can be referenced by the URI(s)
>   returned in the entity of the response, with the most specific URI for
>   the resource given by a Location header field. The response SHOULD
>   include an entity containing a list of resource characteristics and
>   location(s) from which the user or user agent can choose the one most
>   appropriate. The entity format is specified by the media type given in
>   the Content-Type header field. The origin server MUST create the
>   resource before returning the 201 status code. If the action cannot be
>   carried out immediately, the server SHOULD respond with 202 (Accepted)
>   response instead.

If something went wrong, I would argue you shouldn't return `-1` as others have said, but simply a Client or Server Error Code (4xx or 5xx). For example, if a user is not allowed to create some new resource, you would simply return a "401 Unauthorized", nothing more and nothing less.

Comment: What about the body? empty or the entire newly created object in response?

Comment: Two common options I know of are 1) setting the location header to where the new entity can be found, or, 2) including the new entity in the body. I personally go with the latter for practical reasons. Somtimes combined for a more resty feeling ;)